# android externel application

Tags: android

Hi form the following site http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/2.1_r2/
i can download the source code of all android app 
as jar ,i need the videorecording app from the above jar ,is it possible ie by importing jar in to my app and call like default intent calling eg Intent i=new ... Startactivity().